# Xcode 8 Automatically manage signing - bundle id - Ruin My Day

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, xcode8, bundle-identifier

Let's say that my bundle id is `"com.ILoveMistake.mybad"`

I use Unity and the project launch on my iphone : the bundle ID is : com.ILoveMistake.mybad

I select signing `"automatically manage signing"`. Everything works great and a good day was begining. I decide to Product > Archive
I had one error `"the bundle id com.ILoveMistake.mybad doesn't exist bla bla bla I will ruin your day"`

Then I realize that I didn't create my apps on itunes connect or create a bundle id on: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

I discover that on Identifiers , App IDS : There isn't com.ILoveMistake.mybad and when I try to create it, he seems to be "already exist" but invisible...

What can I do ?

Sometime during the day, a bundle identifier appear `"Wildcard XC" with ID`. I try to create the app on itunes connect with the prefix `com.ILoveMistake.mybad`, but the app "already exist" and invisible too...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the problem and that can be solve only by contacting Apple.

You have 2 team, one personal and one "paid". When you click on "automatically manage signing" that create the bundle id on the first team.

But you can't access this first team.

To solve that, you have to ALWAYS create the bundle id first on your "paid" team.